# sqlite3: dump with the drop of the tables

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying to use `sqlite3` to make the dump of a sqlite database:

```
sqlite3 example.sq3 .dump > backup.sql
```

This is an example output:

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "articles" (
"id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
"author_id" INTEGER,
"title" VARCHAR,
"body" TEXT,
"published" VARCHAR(1) DEFAULT 'N'
);
INSERT INTO "articles" VALUES(1,1,'First Article','First Article Body','Y');
INSERT INTO "articles" VALUES(2,3,'Second Article','Second Article Body','Y');
INSERT INTO "articles" VALUES(3,1,'Third Article','Third Article Body','Y');
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "comments" (
"id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
"article_id" INTEGER NOT NULL,
"user_id" INTEGER NOT NULL,
"comment" TEXT,
"published" VARCHAR(1) DEFAULT 'N',
"created" DATETIME,
"updated" DATETIME
);
INSERT INTO "comments" VALUES(1,1,2,'First Comment for First Article','Y','2007-03-18 10:45:23','2007-03-18 10:47:31');
INSERT INTO "comments" VALUES(2,1,4,'Second Comment for First Article','Y','2007-03-18 10:47:23','2007-03-18 10:49:31');
INSERT INTO "comments" VALUES(3,1,1,'Third Comment for First Article','Y','2007-03-18 10:49:23','2007-03-18 10:51:31');
INSERT INTO "comments" VALUES(4,1,1,'Fourth Comment for First Article','N','2007-03-18 10:51:23','2007-03-18 10:53:31');
INSERT INTO "comments" VALUES(5,2,1,'First Comment for Second Article','Y','2007-03-18 10:53:23','2007-03-18 10:55:31');
INSERT INTO "comments" VALUES(6,2,2,'Second Comment for Second Article','Y','2007-03-18 10:55:23','2007-03-18 10:57:31');
DELETE FROM sqlite_sequence;
INSERT INTO "sqlite_sequence" VALUES('articles',3);
INSERT INTO "sqlite_sequence" VALUES('comments',6);
COMMIT;
```

My problem is that the dump, for the table scheme, always uses the statement `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`, while I would like to **drop the existing tables**, because when I import the dump I can not physically erase the existing database that has the same existing tables and records.

I checked the `sqlite3` command options, but I found nothing useful.

How can I do?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such option in the `sqlite3` command-line shell.

You have to create your own dumping tool, or write a script to adjust the SQL output.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I cannot edit Alarch's answer, so here's a fixed version:

```bash
sqlite3 example.sq3 .dump > backup.sql
sed -i 's/CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS \("[^"]*"\) (/DROP TABLE IF EXISTS \1;\n&/' backup.sql
```

Explanation: After dumping the database to `backup.sql`, we use `sed -i` to edit the SQL dump in place and add a `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS` before each line with `CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a simple sed command on your dump file:

```
sed 's/CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS \(.*\) (/DROP TABLE IF EXISTS \1;\n&/' dumpdb.sql
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).